# Unable to create directory and download model on local directory from Azure

Tags: python, azure, pytorch, pipeline

I have created a pipeline script where I have defined the pipeline steps and submit the pipeline.

```
dataPrep_step = PythonScriptStep(name='01 Data Preparation',
                                source_directory='/home/ubuntu/Desktop/AzureMLProject/PytorchProject',
                             script_name='220 - Dataprep Pipeline.py',
                             inputs=[categories_ds.as_named_input('categories_ds'), labels_ds.as_named_input('labels_ds')],
                             outputs=[dataFolder],
                             runconfig=run_config,
                             arguments=['--datafolder', dataFolder])

train_step = PythonScriptStep(name='02 Train the Model',
                             source_directory='/home/ubuntu/Desktop/AzureMLProject/PytorchProject',
                             script_name='220 - Traning Pipeline.py',
                             inputs=[dataFolder],
                             runconfig=run_config,
                             arguments=['--datafolder', dataFolder, '--batch_size', 110, '--num_epochs', 1, '--learning_rate', 0.0001, '--ds', image_files_dataset.as_named_input('my_ds').as_mount()])

steps = [dataPrep_step, train_step]
new_pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps=steps)
```

Now the issue is that when I try to make directory and download the model locally from Azure MODEL, I am unable to do it inside training script (i.e., 220 - Traning Pipeline.py) but the model download successfully inside pipeline script (where I have defined the pipeline steps). I am using following code to download the model from Azure.

```
os.makedirs("/models", exist_ok = True)
azure_model = Model(ws, "pytorch-model")
azure_model.download(target_dir="/models", exist_ok=True)
```

I am not sure why the same code is working fine inside pipeline script but not working inside training script. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline script and training script can have different directory/file paths. Please check and specify the correct **source** and **destination** path of the download file.

For example:

> run.download_file(name='outputs/my_output_file',
> output_file_path='my_destination_path')

References: [Create training scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-1st-experiment-sdk-train#create-training-scripts) and [Configure and submit training runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-set-up-training-targets#submit-the-experiment)